# Spring WebFlux - how to determine when my client has finished working

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-webflux, reactive

I need to call certain API with multiple query params simultaneously, in order to do that I wanted to use reactive approach. I ended up with reactive client that is able to call endpoint based on passed `SearchQuery`, handle pagination of that response and call for remaining pages and returns `Flux<Item>`. So far it works fine, however what I need to do now is to:

- Collect data for all search queries and save them as initial state
- Once the initial data is collected, I need to start repeating those calls in small time intervals and validate each item against initial data. Basically, I need to find new items from here.

But I'm running out of options how to solve that, I came up with probably the dirties solution ever, but I bet there are much better ways to do that.

So first of all, this is relevant code of my client

```
    public Flux<Item> collectData(final SearchQuery query) {
        final var iteration = new int[]{0};
        return invoke(query, 0).expand(res ->
                this.handleResponse(res, query, iteration))
                .flatMap(response -> Flux.fromIterable(response.collectItems()));
    }

    private Mono<ApiResponse> handleResponse(final ApiResponse response, final SearchQuery searchQuery, final int[] iteration) {
        return hasNextPage(response) ? invoke(searchQuery, calculateOffset(++iteration[0])) : Mono.empty();
    }

    private Mono<ApiResponse> invoke(final SearchQuery query, final int offset) {
        final var url = offset == 0 ? query.toUrlParams() : query.toUrlParamsWithOffset(offset);
        return doInvoke(url).onErrorReturn(ApiResponse.emptyResponse());
    }

    private Mono<ApiResponse> doInvoke(final String endpoint) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri(endpoint)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ApiResponse.class);
    }
```

And here is my service that is using this client

```
private final Map<String, Item> initialItems = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

void work() {
    final var executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    queryRepository.getSearchQueries().forEach(query -> {
        reactiveClient.collectData(query).subscribe(item -> initialItems.put(item.getId(), item));
    });

    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        if(isReady()) {
            queryRepository.getSearchQueries().forEach(query -> {
                reactiveClient.collectData(query).subscribe(this::process);
            });
        }
    }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

/**
 *  If after 2 second sleep size of initialItems remains the same,
 *  that most likely means that initial population phase is over,
 *  and we can proceed with further data processing
 **/
private boolean isReady() {
    try {
        final var snapshotSize = initialItems.size();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return snapshotSize == initialItems.size();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think the code speaks for itself, I just want to finish first phase, which is initial data population and then start processing all incomming data.

Comment: So to understand correct, you want to do a call when your service starts, cache the response, then schedule calls and compare to what you have cached? Use the `@Scheduled` annotation to schedule calls on an interval, why the use of expand? just flatmap the response. Since you are not uppdating the hashmap concurrently (since you are doing the update in subscribe) that is not needed.

Comment: and this `queryRepository.getSearchQueries()` is a blocking call since it is not returning a `Flux`.

Comment: `queryRepository.getSearchQueries()` is actually in memory repository (simple `HashMap` that contains data), but yeah this is blocking call. I'm using `expand()` to handle pagination, each response returns up to 60 items and metadata that says how many items are there in total. So based on that and received items count I can decide if I need to make more calls for remaining pages. Other than that, yes, I want to compare new results with cached ones. However, I want to start that comparison after I cache initial results.

Comment: I'm not sure what will solve the `@Scheduled` annotation, is it better than running that with `scheduleAtFixedRate()`? I think that in both solutions I need to somehow signal that caching is done and from that moment I can start collecting new results. I'm not sure how to achieve that... I actually changed implementation right now a bit, for initial calls I'm using few concurrent blocking calls using `RestTemplate`, once they are done they are signaling that and that's when I'm starting non-blocking calls using code above. Not needing to use blocking client would be great improvement tho

Comment: You need to rethink your entire solution. The @Schedule annotation, is a way to simplify have scheduled jobs in spring, with its own executioner. Why you should use it? because then you dont need to setup your entire scheduleAtFixedRate, thats why, one annotation instead of 15 lines of code. And also it will be managed by Spring.

Comment: then when it comes to your solution, you should on each scheduled call you check if the cache is empty, if it is you do your initial call, fetch data and place it in the cache. The next scheduled call you check the cache, see that it is populated, so you do your other type of call, comapre to what you have in cache. Rince repeat.

Comment: and as said before `queryRepository.getSearchQueries()` are blocking calls, these are bad.

Comment: You should avoid mix blocking calls with non blocking calls. Webflux works with a small amount of threads that will not automatically scale up if there is a lot of blocking going on. Which means that if you have "some blocking calls" in the beginning, it has a great potential to become really poor in performance if you have a heavy load. If all threads are blocked, then the queuing will start. Thats why blocking of any sort is really bad in webflux apps. You either go non blocking all the way, or you have a regular non webflux app.Dont mix and match unless you really know what you are doing.